# How do I wrap a span around the last word of an element's inner text, using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, text

I know this should be a simple task but I'm having problems selecting a heading elements last word and wrapping that in a span so I can add style changes.

Here's what I  have so far

```
$('.side-c h3').split(/\s+/).pop().wrap('<span />');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You've probably already thought this through, but it would probably be easier to do this server-side, since many web programming languages have many high-level functions for dealing with text manipulation, while jQuery is meant (like Stephen said) for dealing with DOM nodes. (Man, that was a long run-on sentence.)

Comment: I concur with @eykanal, unless you're building a jQuery plugin of some kind that will be used by other developers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that jQuery objects wrap DOM nodes.  Each word in the element is not a DOM node itself, so you'll need a little more work to break apart the text and rejoin it.  You also need to account for multiple nodes being selected by jQuery.  Try this:

```
$('.side-c h3').each(function(index, element) {
    var heading = $(element), word_array, last_word, first_part;

    word_array = heading.html().split(/\s+/); // split on spaces
    last_word = word_array.pop();             // pop the last word
    first_part = word_array.join(' ');        // rejoin the first words together

    heading.html([first_part, ' <span>', last_word, '</span>'].join(''));
});
```

Comment: it kinda works! but it rewrites the headings for all of them on the page

Comment: Oh, you have multiple `.side-c h3` ? I'll rewrite my answer.

Comment: One final update.  You should be good to go with this new sample.  Let me know if you want this explained.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, you've just made my evening... which, until this point was torturous.. :)

Comment: This is great! Just stumbled on this in some google and was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Glenn That's why I love stackoverflow!

Answer (score 2):

This does it:

```
$('.side-c h3').each(function(){
   var $this = $(this), text=$this.text().trim(), words = text.split(/\s+/);
   var lastWord = words.pop();
   words.push('<span>' + lastWord + '</span>');
   $this.html(words.join(' '));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, this isn't particularly easy.  The most orthodox way to do this is with `DOMNode.splitText`:

```
$('.side-c h3').each(function(){
    var oldNode = this.firstChild,
        newNode = oldNode.splitText(oldNode.data.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1), // don't wrap the space
        span = document.createElement('span');

    this.replaceChild(span, newNode);
    span.appendChild(newNode);
});
```

[See jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49PmS/).